# More than 2gb of Music without paid plan possible?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I do not have a paid plan for UbuntuOne and do not intend of buying one, but I do like to buy music from the UbuntuOne Music Store. Is it possible to buy music, once I bought more than 2gb or would I have to move the music out of the UbuntuOne share?

In this case, I would suggest to put the music in the official ubuntuone-folder instead of a hidden one. Non-technical users will not understand, why their shared music files are not in this folder, but others are popping up there (e.g. in the webinterface).

Best Regards,
Lars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatHappensIfIGoOverMyStorageQuotaByPurchasingMusic

Comment: Ah, did not find that one before - thank you!